# html/css no background image

Tags: html, css

Having problems getting my background image to appear tried a couple of    different things and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: please try to use editor and reproduce behavior in here. screenshot will no giving us enough information of your project structure

Comment: I would suggest to check Image file path and in your case it should be placed in root folder just beside index.html

Comment: whats the path to your image?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try inline css like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(image.png)">
Something inside
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: really not a good idea to recommend inline styles. This shouldn't be considered even as a last resort.

Comment: what would be the best style

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use inline style css just let the body out of style tags, It will looks like this :

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
         body {
         background-image:url(image.png);
         }
       </style>
     </head>
 <body>
  <form>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my bad english. I'm Indonesian

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code you wrote out added my image name and it worked fine idk what i did wrong but i could not get it to work. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Please don't post screenshots of the code, and secondly WHERE style tag going? every thing looks messy out there. And check if the image is in the same directory (means folder) as the HTML file itself and use something like  `body {background-image:url('2d_image.jpeg'). And write your code neatly!

Comment: And it's not necessary to use these kind of fancy editors to do HTML , you can stick to notepad and firefox since you're not going to code a lot!

Comment: sorry my first thread I ever posted   I have my image right under my index.html file in the same folder. very messy just trial and error right now.  I can add pictures no problem can change the color of my background just cant set a background image to save my life